# Java servlet make a html page unavailable and decorate it

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, intellij-idea

I'm using IntellijIdea Ultimate to create a Java Servlet. There are some .html pages(page1.html, page2.html, ...).

When I get on the servlet first, the servlet must return page1.html. This html pages must not be accessible directly, but only using the servlet. More, the servlet must decorate this pages using a file with rules:

```
       page1->next = page2; 
       page2->next = page3; page2->back=page1;
```

so at the first requests the servlet will return page1 decorated with a form whose action is the same servlet and a button with the value "Page 2". How can I decorate these pages dynamically and make it not accessible(accessible only using the servlet - in IntellijIdea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the files under WEB-INF to make them inaccessible.  Then in your servlet, instead of using `response.sendRedirect` use a dispatcher to forward.

```
request.setAttribute("someVariable", listOfStuff);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page1.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

To do anything meaningful, however, you probably need to start using .jsp rather than .html

Like when you say you want the servlet to "decorate" the page...that's not how it works.

You need the file being forwarded to to be a JSP, and you will use JSP code, e.g. JSTL, to do something with request attributes passed to it from the servlet.  That's how you will "decorate" the page.  See the [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for more on that.